# Is $p(\sum_{i=1}^{k}\frac{Y_i}{k}-\frac{\sigma}{k}>x)$ a nondecreasing function of $k$?

Tags: probability-theory

$Y_i$ is i.i.d. and follows Bernoulli distribution with success probability of $\delta$.

Then is the following function nondecreasing with $k$?

$p(\sum_{i=1}^{k}\frac{Y_i}{k}$$-\frac{\sigma}{k}>x)$ where $\sigma>0$ and $k$ is a positive integer.

Comment: Is $x$ just a fixed real number? Or a fixed Integer?

Comment: @CadeReinberger $x$ is a fixed real number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, since we have Bernoulli trials we have the binomial distribution (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution) if you're unfamiliar) we can denote with an $X$. So if $$X = \sum_{i=1}^k Y_i $$ then the probability $X$ takes a value $j$ is given by $$P(X = j) = \delta^j(1-\delta)^{k-j} {k \choose j}  $$

So what you're interested in is $$P(X-\sigma>kx) = P(X>kx+\sigma) = \sum_{j = kx+\sigma}^{k}P(X=j)=\sum_{j=kx+\sigma}^k \delta^j(1-\delta)^{k-j}{k \choose j}$$

With the implied notion that the summation lower bound will likely not be integral and you should take it's ceiling as the lower bound, unless it is integral in which case the lower bound is one more than that integer. (If you prefer the lower bound can most properly be written, then as $\left \lfloor kx+\sigma\right \rfloor +1$)

We call this probability $f(k)$, then to determine if $f$ is nondecreasing, consider $f(k+1)-f(k)$.

$$f(k+1)-f(k) =\sum_{j=\lfloor kx+\sigma+x\rfloor +1}^{k+1}\delta^j(1-\delta)^{k+1-j}{k+1 \choose j} - \sum_{j=\lfloor kx+\sigma \rfloor +1}^k \delta^j(1-\delta)^{k-j}{k \choose j}  $$

Notice that a lot of these terms are pretty similar, and so in particular, write

$$f(k+1)-f(k) = \delta^{k+1} + \sum_{j=\lfloor kx+\sigma+x\rfloor +1}^k \left(\delta^j(1-\delta)^{k+1-j}{k+1 \choose j} - \delta^j(1-\delta)^{k-j}{k \choose j}\right) - \delta^{\lfloor kx+\sigma \rfloor +1}(1-\delta)^{k-1-\lfloor kx+\sigma \rfloor}{k \choose \lfloor kx+\sigma \rfloor +1 } $$

where the last term is only summed over only if $\lfloor kx+\sigma + x \rfloor > \lfloor kx + \sigma \rfloor$. And note since the we want the lower bound in our summation for $f(k)$ to be less than it's upper bound and $\sigma >0$ that $x <1$, so we have at most one term we might takeaway.

Ignoring the takeaway term, under many cases we simplify this sum greatly. Note that $$ {k+1 \choose j } = \frac{(k+1)!}{(j)! (k+1-j)!} = \frac{k+1}{k-j+1} \frac{k!}{j!(k-j)!} = \frac{k+1}{k-j+1}{k \choose j}  $$ And so in the cases where there is no "rollover" and we ignore the takeaway term we get $$ f(k+1)-f(k) = \delta^{k+1} + \sum_{j=\lfloor kx+\sigma+x\rfloor +1}^k \delta^j (1-\delta)^{k-j} {k \choose j} \left( (1-\delta) \frac{k+1}{k-j+1}-1\right) $$

And maybe you can imagine making that pretty close to zero for a pretty small $k$ and a pretty high $\delta$. So if you choose such values, and then add in the rollover term you might see a negative difference.

And indeed, computation shows that it's quite easy to find places with rollover that decrease the function. For instance, here are three examples in Mathematica that were pretty easy to come up with.

[image]

So in general, the answer is **no**, because we've given examples where the function is not increasing.

The more general question of for which parameters is this a non decreasing function of $k$ could probably be tackled through more careful or clever analysis of our sum for $f(k+1)-f(k)$. But, for any nonzero $x$, there will be some rollover point, and so it may even be the case that this always decreases at some point and there are no parameters for which this is non-decreasing.

One more thought that might help if you're interested in the more general case. Note that this function of $k$ does approach some limit as $k$ gets large. Indeed, by the [Demoivre-Laplace Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Moivre%E2%80%93Laplace_theorem) (or by some other approximation, perhaps with a Poisson distribution) we can approximate this probability for large $k$ with a normal distribution. $$\lim_{k \to \infty} f(k) = \lim_{k \to \infty }\int_{kx+\sigma}^k  \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi k \delta (1-\delta)}}e^{\frac{-(j-k\delta)^2}{2k\delta(1-\delta)}}  \ \text{d}j$$ One can then imagine numerically bounding this from above and trying to maximize $f(k)$. If you can ever find a specific value for our probability $f(k)$ that you can show is greater than this limit, then at some point there must be decrease. In general I think from some light numerics, however, that the convergence is often from below, so perhaps a more sophisticated argument could be used, but the more general problem, if not solved by a better analysis of our sum for $f(k+1)-f(k)$, could possibly be solved by some convergence argument.